# Components of a Vector Field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

This may be quite a petty question, but it's been bothering me for a while.

So for the vector fields $X$ and $Y$, we can write them in component form as

$X=X^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\space \space \space $ and $\space \space \space Y=Y^{\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$

(and we'll abbreviate these as $X=X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$ and $Y=Y^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}$).

In finding $[X,Y]$ it seems to suffice to show

$[X,Y]=XY-YX=X(Y^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})-Y(X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})=(X^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}Y^{\mu}-Y^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}X^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}$ $\space \space \space \space$ (1)

However, does this work:

$[X,Y]=XY-YX=X^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(Y^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})-Y^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})$

then apply the product rule to get

$X^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(Y^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}+X^{\nu}Y^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}-Y^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(X^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}-Y^{\nu}X^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}$    $\space \space \space \space$ (2)

I can't see why this isn't formally correct? And if so, the second and the fourth term cancel, or are they both zero? Or is (1) just a simplified version of (2) and if fact none of the terms are zero nor cancel. And why?

Comment: The terms cancel, you can commute the elements of the canonical basis because everything is smooth.

Comment: So $[\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}]=0$ and $[X^{\mu},Y^{\nu}]=0$?

Comment: Both are correct. Note that when you sum everything the second term and the fourth will cancel. However, in fact, even if the first one was incorrect, when you sum everything up the terms will be canceled too.

Comment: So you're saying (as above) $[\partial_{\mu},\partial_{\nu}]=0$ and $[X^{\mu},Y^{\nu}]=0$ but $[X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu},Y^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}] \neq 0$? Why?

Comment: Ok, I think you´re confusing when the summation happens. Your statement in the comment above is correct, your third commutator is exact equals (2) without Einstein´s convention, but with Einstein convention the second and fourth term will cancel in (2).

Comment: Ok, I think you figured out my confusion perfectly! So to make sure I understand: you can swap around all the $\partial_{\mu}$'s with each other, and the $X^{\mu}$'s and $Y^{\mu}$'s with each other, but of course $[X^{\mu},\partial_{\nu}] \neq 0$? Hence the second and fourth term cancel, but the first and third don't?This is quite a messy way of saying what I mean but hopefully you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Yes to both questions